# MySql REGEXP multiple words search

Tags: php, sql, regex, database, search

search from databse with REGEXP

I have a phrase of a few words that I want to search in the database but it does not output, but with the same command if it is a word, it finds values and does not find for two words or more

```
keyword = 'یوسف نبی'
pattern: [يىئۦ][ً-ٰٓـ]*[وؤۥ][ً-ٰٓـ]*س[ً-ٰٓـ]*ف[ً-ٰٓـ]*+[ً-ٰٓـ]*ن[ً-ٰٓـ]*ب[ً-ٰٓـ]*[يىئۦ][ً-ٰٓـ]*

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` REGEXP '{$_POST['pattern']}'

no result
```

Comment: Could you rewrite your question using the latin alphabet?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Regex looks looks like it is missing a closing bracket on a character class... could be the RTL though, seems to be erring the question display.... Likely unrelated but `$_POST` should not go in SQL. Bind the value.

Comment: To make the question clearer, show a small example. Show a tiny database with a few entries. Then show at least two examples: an input that works, and what the output is. An input that does not work as expected, and what the output is (if its empty, say that).

Comment: @user3783243 the character classes seem well-formed to me. I'm entirely unsure how MySQL handles RTL when matching with Regexp, and whether Regexp rules should be written RTL or LTR... and e.g. whether for example `[abc_-]` (dash in last position if not range) should be on the right, or the left, in a RTL expression!

Comment: @MarkusAO Might be my browser's rendering. After the 4th character classes seem to not be closed. Copying and pasting though they do appear correct.